# Isso no site sensacionalista é um slide ou tem algum outro nome?

Tags: webdesign

Logo no inicio onde tem essa galeria de imagens http://sensacionalista.uol.com.br/

Tem algum nome especifico para isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não tem nenhum nome específico, ele não usou nenhuma biblioteca tipo o boostrap ou angular, só combinou várias divs e muito css pra criar esse efeito.